# Netflix vs ReactiveX RxJava-Android library

Tags: android, rx-java

Quick question: I'm playing with RxJava for the first time. The writers of the tutorials I've seen all dive into *how* to use it, but none of them have talked about the differences between the ReactiveX and Netflix versions of the libraries. And to confuse things, the mvnrepository link to the Netfix GitHub redirects to ReactiveX:

- https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

So, some tutorials say to do this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
}
```

And others say to do this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.20.7'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
}
```

Even different answers on the same SO question seem to use the two interchangeably:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22909505/4151208
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32972674/4151208

And clearly they're not the same. I found that the `AndroidObservable` class was not available in the ReactiveX version. Only the Netflix version. Obviously the version numbers are different...

I'm I missing something? Is this just a lack of clarity in the documentation I've been reading? Am I reading the wrong documentation? Can someone point me to a good place that I can RTFM in regards to the above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same library.  Versions < 1.0.0 had `com.netflix.rxjava` groupId, but 1.0.0 and above have the `io.reactivex` groupId. See this [changelog item](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/CHANGES.md#change-log).  To get the latest and most stable, you want to be using the reactivex groupId.

`AndroidObservable` was deprecated and removed at some point, which is why it only exists in older versions.

Tutorials that refer to the netflix version were likely written awhile ago and have not been updated.

Comment: Awesome! So, is it safe to say that `AndroidObservable.fromBroadcast(this, intentFilter)` is equivalent to `Observable.create(new OperatorBroadcastRegister(this, intentFilter, null, null))`?

Comment: I can't really say, I've not used either. I don't believe either exist as of version 1.0.0.  The rx-android library was significantly pared down on that release and some, but not all, of the removed work was moved to other projects. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGES.md#version-100---august-5th-2015

Comment: Yeah, `OperatorBroadcastRegister` is also one of those deprecated classes. I've been in the game for years, so I should know better, but this is confusing. Thanks for the help.